# Getting error while sending transaction over bigchaindb node

Tags: tendermint, bigchaindb

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Bigchaindb ver: 2.0.0
Tendermint ver: 0.31.5-d2eab536

Setup: 1 node bigchaindb+tendermint - running as a docker container

Problem: Bigchaindb starts fine and tendermint connects successfully to it.  However, when transactions are committed, the commit fails with errors logged in `bigchaindb.log` mentioning unable to connect to localhost:26657.  `netstat` command doesn't show any process listening on 26657.  Moreover, `tendermint.out.log` shows: 
**E[2020-05-03|19:19:48.586] abci.socketClient failed to connect to tcp://127.0.0.1:26658.  Retrying... module=abci-client connection=query err="dial tcp 127.0.0.1:26658: conn
ect: connection refused"**

However, as in the below netstat output, the port is in listen mode and bigchaindb.log shows tendermint as conncted:

```
[2020-05-03 19:19:51] [INFO] (abci.app)  ABCIServer started on port: 26658 (MainProcess - pid: 35)
[2020-05-03 19:19:51] [INFO] (abci.app)  ... connection from Tendermint: 127.0.0.1:59392 ... (MainProcess - pid: 35)
[2020-05-03 19:19:51] [INFO] (abci.app)  ... connection from Tendermint: 127.0.0.1:59394 ... (MainProcess - pid: 35)
[2020-05-03 19:19:51] [INFO] (abci.app)  ... connection from Tendermint: 127.0.0.1:59396 ... (MainProcess - pid: 35)
[2020-05-03 19:19:51] [INFO] (bigchaindb.core) Tendermint version: 0.31.5-d2eab536 (MainProcess - pid: 35)
```

Output of netstat:

```
bash-5.0# netstat -anp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2812            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32/monit
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9984            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      48/gunicorn: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9985            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      54/bigchaindb_ws
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:26658           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      35/bigchaindb
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:26658         127.0.0.1:59394         ESTABLISHED 35/bigchaindb
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59394         127.0.0.1:26658         ESTABLISHED 37/tendermint
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:26658         127.0.0.1:59392         ESTABLISHED 35/bigchaindb
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.2:33424        172.31.28.97:27017      ESTABLISHED 35/bigchaindb
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.2:33426        172.31.28.97:27017      ESTABLISHED 35/bigchaindb
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59392         127.0.0.1:26658         ESTABLISHED 37/tendermint
tcp        0      6 127.0.0.1:26658         127.0.0.1:59396         ESTABLISHED 35/bigchaindb
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.2:34490        172.31.28.97:27017      ESTABLISHED 53/gunicorn: worker
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59396         127.0.0.1:26658         ESTABLISHED 37/tendermint
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.2:34488        172.31.28.97:27017      ESTABLISHED 53/gunicorn: worker
tcp        0      0 :::2812                 :::*                    LISTEN      32/monit
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node PID/Program name    Path
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3426959421 54/bigchaindb_ws    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3426959420 54/bigchaindb_ws
```

The problem is random.  Sometimes, it gets connected magically and tendermint rpc process listens to 26657 port.

Stacktrace from bigchaindb.log:

```
[2020-05-03 19:29:12] [ERROR] (bigchaindb.web.server) Exception on /api/v1/transactions/ [POST] (bigchaindb_webapi - pid: 53)                                                
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 157, in _new_conn                                                                                      
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw                                                                                                                    
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection                                                                          
    raise err                                                                                                                                                                
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection                                                                          
    sock.connect(sa)                                                                                                                                                         
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused                                                                                                                       

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                          

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen                                                                                    
    chunked=chunked,                                                                                                                                                         
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request                                                                              
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)                                                                                                                          
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in request                                                                                                            
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request                                                                                                      
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)                                                                                                                     
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders                                                                                                         
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output                                                                                                       
    self.send(msg)                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send                                                                                                                
    self.connect()                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 184, in connect                                                                                        
    conn = self._new_conn()                                                                                                                                                  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn                                                                                      
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e                                                                                                                     
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3fa4a31a90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused    

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                          

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send                                                                                            
    timeout=timeout                                                                                                                                                          
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen                                                                                    
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]                                                                                                          
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment                                                                                      
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))                                                                                                           
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=26657): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPC

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                          

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request                                                                                  
    rv = self.dispatch_request()                                                                                                                                             
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request                                                                                       
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)                                                                                                               
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 458, in wrapper                                                                                    
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                         
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 89, in view                                                                                                   
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                            
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 573, in dispatch_request                                                                           
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                             
  File "/usr/src/app/bigchaindb/web/views/transactions.py", line 99, in post                                                                                                 
    status_code, message = bigchain.write_transaction(tx_obj, mode)                                                                                                          
  File "/usr/src/app/bigchaindb/lib.py", line 100, in write_transaction                                                                                                      
    response = self.post_transaction(transaction, mode)                                                                                                                      
  File "/usr/src/app/bigchaindb/lib.py", line 95, in post_transaction                                                                                                        
    return requests.post(self.endpoint, json=payload)                                                                                                                        
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post                                                                                                 
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)                                                                                                              
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request                                                                                               
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)                                                                                                                 
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request                                                                                         
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)                                                                                                                                    
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send                                                                                            
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                      
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send                                                                                            
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)                                                                                                                                
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=26657): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HT
```

How do I troubleshoot this?

Internet references:

1) Issue: https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb-driver/issues/499 
2) Tried steps mentioned in: https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb/issues/2581#issuecomment-455952861

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sample code that used to test: (copied from https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb/issues/2581#issuecomment-455958416 )

Note: localhost:10001 is mapped to 0.0.0.0:9984 of the respective container.

```
from bigchaindb_driver import BigchainDB
from bigchaindb_driver.crypto import generate_keypair

bdb_root_url = 'http://localhost:10001'
bdb = BigchainDB(bdb_root_url)

msg = 'Varadhan test message for bigchaindb'

alice = generate_keypair()
tx = bdb.transactions.prepare(
    operation='CREATE',
    signers=alice.public_key,
    asset={'data': {'message': msg}})
signed_tx = bdb.transactions.fulfill(
    tx,
    private_keys=alice.private_key)
bdb.transactions.send_commit(signed_tx) # write
block_height = bdb.blocks.get(txid=signed_tx['id'])
block = bdb.blocks.retrieve(str(block_height)) # read
print(block)
```

EDIT-2: I tried running tendermint with log level set to debug and got:

```
bash-5.0# tendermint node --rpc.laddr "tcp://0.0.0.0:26657" --log_level="*:debug"
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.136] Starting multiAppConn                        module=proxy impl=multiAppConn
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.137] Starting socketClient                        module=abci-client connection=query impl=socketClient
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.138] Starting socketClient                        module=abci-client connection=mempool impl=socketClient
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.139] Starting socketClient                        module=abci-client connection=consensus impl=socketClient
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.139] Starting EventBus                            module=events impl=EventBus
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.140] Starting PubSub                              module=pubsub impl=PubSub
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.151] Starting IndexerService                      module=txindex impl=IndexerService
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.231] ABCI Handshake App Info                      module=consensus height=355 hash= software-version= protocol-version=0
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.233] ABCI Replay Blocks                           module=consensus appHeight=355 storeHeight=2760414 stateHeight=2760413
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.233] Applying block                               module=consensus height=356
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.315] Executed block                               module=consensus height=356 validTxs=0 invalidTxs=0
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.395] Applying block                               module=consensus height=357
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.519] Executed block                               module=consensus height=357 validTxs=0 invalidTxs=0
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.599] Applying block                               module=consensus height=358
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.723] Executed block                               module=consensus height=358 validTxs=0 invalidTxs=0
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.803] Applying block                               module=consensus height=359
I[2020-05-06|18:40:05.927] Executed block                               module=consensus height=359 validTxs=0 invalidTxs=0
I[2020-05-06|18:40:06.007] Applying block                               module=consensus height=360
I[2020-05-06|18:40:06.131] Executed block                               module=consensus height=360 validTxs=0 invalidTxs=0
```

As can be seen, RPC server module is not loaded at all.  Is there more debugging options available to see why RPC server module is not loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting 2 instances using tendermint genesis file and then commit transaction. Tendermint is not able to find peer for transaction. Also the tendermint port should be open to allow the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

## Ensure bigchaindb server is running before starting tendermint

you can do the following if you installed bigchaindb using docker:

1. `make stop`
2. `make start`
3. `make run`

or if you don't mind loosing your data

1. `make stop`
2. `make clean`
3. `make start`
4. `make run`

## Also ensure you allow required ports through firewall

Add port 26656, 26657, 26658, 9984, 9985 through firewall in your machine and also run

`ufw allow 26656` , `ufw allow 26657` , `ufw allow 26658` , `ufw allow 9984` and `ufw allow 9985` on ssh